# How to construct a progress bar from the given percentage?

Tags: javascript, python, progress-bar

Hello I have a variable with the percentages like this:

```
test = "3%, 7%, 10%, 11%, 50%, 75%, 77%, 82%, 91%, 100%"
```

It's a Python/Django variable.

Now, I want to use those numbers to construct a progress bar using Javascript.

I am dumping the variable test as json like:

```
json.dumps(test)
```

How do I call it in Javascript and construct the progress bar out of it? Thanks

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more clear about what you're really trying to do.  What exact javascript data are you putting into the web page?  When you say "construct a progress bar" out of the data, what do you mean?  A progress bar is a widget that displays a particular percent completion at any given point in time.  Your code generally feeds it completion information multiple times as your operation proceeds and the progress bar converts that information into a visual display.  It is not clear what your question is really asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not expect someone to do this kind of work for you, you need to do it yourself. I have provided you with a short example and explanation to help you *understand* what is going on, the rest is up to you.

Here is a command line example in Python:

```
import sys, time
print

pers = [3, 7, 10, 11, 50, 75, 77, 82, 91, 100]
for per in pers:
    sys.stdout.write('\r[%s>%s]' % (
        ('=' * ((per / 2) -1)), ' '*(50-(per/2)))
    )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)

print
print
```

Do you understand what is happening here? The basic concept is that you add to the progress out of the total. So, here i used `time.sleep(0.5)` to add random time in so you can actually see the progress, but when you are writing your javascript code, this will be progressing as whatever you need is loading.

So, once you grasp this idea, simply repeat the same sort of thing in javascript, except instead of adding characters to a string, you are expanding the width of a rectangle or something. And, you want to show progress out of the whole, so you should probably have an identical rectangle already full width directly behind the progress one, showing the total it has left to load. Then format these rectangles with css to make them look nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://1.s3.envato.com/files/2526201/index.html) and understand yourself how to do it.

If getting value from the string is your question, you can use `split()` and/or regular expression to get an array of values from the string/json object.